# Why I keep getting an error of MAX_ELEMENTS_EXCEEDED when I don't overpass the daily free number of requests?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

So I developed a code where I read a file with some locations (15 to be more precise), where the first one is the depot and the other 14 locations are the places where a bus needs to pass to collect patients. In order to do that, I use Google Maps API key in order to collect the real distances and write them in a .txt file in the end.

```
import pandas as pd
import googlemaps
from itertools import tee
import numpy as np

#Read CSV file into data frame named 'df'
#change seperator (sep e.g. ',') type if necessary
df = pd.read_csv("D:/Utilizadores/Documents/FEUP/2018-2019/1º Semestre/PDI/Relatório/locais2.txt", sep='\\t',
                       engine='python', skiprows=[0], names=["address", "latitude", "longitude"])

lat = np.expand_dims(np.array(df["latitude"]), 1)
lon = np.expand_dims(np.array(df["longitude"]), 1)
coordinates = np.concatenate((lat, lon), axis=1)

coordinates = list(coordinates)
coordinates = [list(coor) for coor in coordinates]


#Perform request to use the Google Maps API web service
#API_key = 'AIzaSyCi8DDz_CCiVwW2JtvT6i-XpJYiEwxFryI'
API_key = 'AIzaSyCpumDcRbbteV64xlGOUQ5_Bah8Ja5gdJ4'
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=API_key)

result = gmaps.distance_matrix(coordinates, coordinates, mode='driving')["rows"]
distance_matrix = np.zeros((len(result), len(result)))

for i in range(len(result)):
    for j in range(len(result)):
        distance_matrix[i, j] = result[i]["elements"][j]["distance"]["value"]

np.savetxt("D:/Utilizadores/Documents/FEUP/2018-2019/1º Semestre/PDI/Relatório/locais_output.txt", distance_matrix, delimiter=",", fmt='%d')
print(distance_matrix)
```

The distances I want are from one place to every place, so the result I want is a matrix of 15x15 where the diagonal is filled with 0's. But it keeps printing this error:

```
"googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError: MAX_ELEMENTS_EXCEEDED".
```

The only way to not have an error is to put a limit on the reading of the file of 10 locations, including the depot:

```
result = gmaps.distance_matrix(coordinates[0:10], coordinates[0:10], mode='driving')["rows"]
```

Why is that? Anyone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#StatusCodes)

> MAX_ELEMENTS_EXCEEDED indicates that the product of origins and destinations exceeds the per-query [limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing).

from ["usage and billing"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing):

> Each query sent to the Distance Matrix API generates elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations equals the number of elements.
>
> **Other Usage Limits**
>   While you are no longer limited to a maximum number of elements per day (EPD), the following usage limits are still in place for the Distance Matrix API:
>
> Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request.
>   Maximum 100 elements per server-side request.
>   Maximum 100 elements per client-side request.
>   1000 elements per second (EPS), calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

15 x 15 = 225 which is greater than the maximum allowed (100)

That you don't want or need some of the responses is not relevant.